# how to make loop in this case?

Tags: c, int, boolean, do-while

I need   compute the first 100 prime numbers, but in the output i got "9" and other in my numbers....................... i want compute the first 100 prime numbers

```
{
bool prime; int start, new, kor,k, i,gg;
start=1; 
k=1 ;
gg=0;
do 
{ 

    if (start < 2) {new = 2;}
    if (start == 2) {new = 3;}
    if (start > 2) { 
        if ((new % 2) == 0) 
        new--; 
        do {
            prime  = true; 
            kor=sqrt(new); 
            new+=2;
            for (i=3;prime&& (i<=kor); i+=2) {
                            if (new % i == 0) 
                                prime=false;}
        } while (!prime) ;    
    }  
    gg++;
    printf("%d->%d\n",gg, new);
    k++;
    start++;
    continue;
} 
    while (k<101);

}
```

Comment: you should mention your programming language so we do not need to guess. this also increases visibility within stackoverflow.

Comment: I presume this is C, since it uses a variable called 'new'?

Comment: C doesn't have bool types

Comment: even so c and it's friends do not enforce it, even such code can profit from clear indentation.

Comment: C does have a boolean type, named `_Bool`, and according to N1570 7.18 2, if you include `<stdbool.h>` "The macro `bool` expands to `_Bool`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
if (start < 2) {new = 2;}
if (start == 2) {new = 3;}
```

you have special cases the first and second numbers.
Next time round the `do...while` loop we skip the for loop because `kor` is 1, thereby printing 5. Which we didn't check, so perhaps we just got lucky. Smells like we don't check far enough.

Next time, after

```
kor=sqrt(new1); new1+=2;
```

`kor` is 2, so again we don't do the for loop, and print 7. Next time we have the same situation. kor is still 2 so you get 9.

I *think* if you switch the `new+=2` to *before* the `kor=sqrt(1);` it will work.
Once you are in this part, you don't need to check if something is even, since you always add 2 to an odd number.
BTW Why does it say `continue` as the last thing in the loop?
This might be better (I took the liberty of putting it in a function):

```
void find_primes()
{
    bool prime; int start, new, kor,k, i,gg;
    start=1; k=1 ;gg=0; 
    do 
    { 
        if (start < 2) {new = 2;}
        if (start == 2) {new = 3;}
        if (start > 2) { 
            do {
                prime = true;
                new+=2;
                kor=sqrt(new);
                for (i=3;prime&& (i<=kor); i+=2) {
                    if (new % i == 0) 
                        prime=false;
                }
            } 
            while (!prime) ;
        }
        gg++; printf("%d->%d\n",gg, new); 
        k++;
        start++;
    }
    while (k<101);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're programming in, so I'm taking a guess at this (I can't comment yet)-

Are you getting all odd numbers as output in your answer? 9, 11, 13, 15...
It seems that you are printing out all values of 'new', regardless of whether prime is true or not. Maybe you should put a

```
if (prime) {
    printf("%d->%d\n",gg, new);
}
```

there

Comment: i want compute the first 100 prime numbers

Comment: need      while , its loop

Answer (score 0):

```
here is an example program from: 
    http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-for-prime-number

note: 1 is not a prime number, see:
    http://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html




#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i = 3, count, c;

    printf("Enter the number of prime numbers required\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if ( n >= 1 )
    {
        printf("First %d prime numbers are :\n",n);
        printf("2\n");
    }

    for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;  )
    {
        for ( c = 2 ; c <= (i - 1) ; c++ )
        {
            if ( i%c == 0 ) break;
        }

        if ( c == i )
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```